# Two way communication between two functional React JS components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I have two functional components built in React, one is an *Item* component - it holds some data about stuff, with optional graphics, some text data and price information. On the bottom there is a button, that allows you to select this particular item. It also keeps information in its props on ID of currently selected *Item* - that's how i planned to solve this problem.

My second component is a *ItemList* - it basically holds a list of aforemetioned Items - plus it sorts all the items and must keep information about which component is currently selected - the selected one basically looks different - some stuff like the border box and button's colour gets switched via CSS.

My logic to implement goes like this - when user clicks on a "Select" button of a particular Item, the Item should change its look (unless it's already selected, then do nothing), after that somehow propagate info up onto the *ItemList*, so that it can "disable" the previously selected component. There can be only one selected *Item*, and once user decide to select another one, the previously selected should change its state and go back to unselected standard graphic style.

I've ran across a solution with state in the *ItemList* component plus passing a function via props into *Item*, but that doesn't solve the second part - *ItemList* needs to get info about a change, so it can rerender all the components according to actual state. What part of React API should I dive into to solve this issue?

Here is code for my components:

*Item*

```
interface Props {
    receivedObject: itemToDisplay;
    selectedItemId: string;
    onClick?: () => void;
}

export default function Item(props: Props) {
    const {name, description, price} = props.receivedObject;
    const imageUrl = props.receivedObject?.media?.mainImage?.small?.url;
    const priceComponent = <Price price={price}/>;
    const [isItemSelected, setSelection] = useState(props.selectedItemId == props.receivedObject.id);
    const onClick = props.onClick || (() => {
        setSelection(!isItemSelected)
    });
    return (
        <>
            <div className="theDataHolderContainer">
            // displayed stuff goes here
                <div className="pickButtonContainer">
                    // that's the button which should somehow send info "upwards" about the new selected item
                    <Button outline={isItemSelected} color="danger" onClick={onClick}>{isItemSelected ? "SELECTED" : "SELECT"}</Button>
                </div>

            </div>
        </>)
};
```

*ItemList*

```
interface Props {
    packageItems: Array<itemToDisplay>
}

export default function ItemList(props: Props) {
    const itemsToDisplay = props.packageItems;
    itemsToDisplay.sort((a, b) =>
        a.price.finalPrice - b.price.finalPrice
    );
    let selectedItemId = itemsToDisplay[0].id;
    const [currentlySelectedItem, changeCurrentlySelectedItem] = useState(selectedItemId);

    const setSelectedItemFunc = () => { 
        /* this function should be passed down as a prop, however it can only 
         * have one `this` reference, meaning that `this` will refer to singular `Item`
         * how do I make it change state in the `ItemList` component?
         */
    
        console.log('function defined in list');
    };
    return(
        <div className="packageNameList">
            <Item
                key={itemsToDisplay[0].id}
                receivedObject={itemsToDisplay[0]}
                onClick={setSelectedItemFunc}
            />

            {itemsToDisplay.slice(1).map((item) => (
                <Item
                    key={item.id}
                    receivedObject={item}
                    onClick={setSelectedItemFunc}
                />
                ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In React, [the data flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down), so you'd better hold state data in a stateful component that renders presentation components.

```js
function ListItem({ description, price, selected, select }) {
  return (
    <li className={"ListItem" + (selected ? " selected" : "")}>
      <span>{description}</span>
      <span>${price}</span>
      <button onClick={select}>{selected ? "Selected" : "Select"}</button>
    </li>
  );
}

function List({ children }) {
  return <ul className="List">{children}</ul>;
}

function Content({ items }) {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState("");
  const createClickHandler = React.useCallback(
    id => () => setSelectedId(id),
    []
  );

  return (
    <List>
      {items
        .sort(({ price: a }, { price: b }) => a - b)
        .map(item => (
          <ListItem
            key={item.id}
            {...item}
            selected={item.id === selectedId}
            select={createClickHandler(item.id)}
          />
        ))}
    </List>
  );
}

function App() {
  const items = [
    { id: 1, description: "#1 Description", price: 17 },
    { id: 2, description: "#2 Description", price: 13 },
    { id: 3, description: "#3 Description", price: 19 }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Content items={items} />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.List > .ListItem {
  margin: 5px;
}
.ListItem {
  padding: 10px;
}
.ListItem > * {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.ListItem:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.ListItem.selected {
  background-color: darkgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, that is a really simple answer, I was diving into context and some more advanced concepts of React in order to solve it, big up :)